# Restore commit was force remove Github

Tags: git, github

I committed my project .
But t want remove that commit but keep that code to next commit.
I used this code:

```
 // now commit is A

 git reset --soft 9c74193 
 // 9c74193   is old commit

 git commit -m "My commit" `

 git push -f  origin master
```

I want restore commit A.
Can I do it ? And how ?

> Thank you so much.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "restore commit A"? Please explain more about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You mean to revert the commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was done recently, and you still have the local repo in which you ran the above commands, then the reflog probably still has a reference to commit `A`.

```
$ git reflog
dd3f691 HEAD@{0}: commit: My Commit
9c74193 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to 9c74193
aaaaaaa HEAD@{2}: commit: A

$ git checkout HEAD@{2}
```

If you've been moving the `HEAD` pointer around a lot, you could also check a branch-specific reflog

```
$ git reflog master
dd3f691 master@{0}: commit: My Commit
9c74193 master@{1}: reset: moving to 9c74193
aaaaaaa master@{2}: commit: A

$ git checkout master@{2}
```

Once you checkout `A` you'll be in detached head state.  You can force-move an existing branch to here if you're sure that's what you want.  (For example, if the earlier force-push created problems for other developers and you're trying to fix it the way it was before, you could `git branch -f master`.)  Or you could create a new branch or tag here, or whatever.

Of course this may require another force push (e.g. if you are indeed moving `master` back from whence it came).

Comment: Thank you!
I  restored my code.
But i see "9c74193 HEAD@{25}",  what is the difference
 ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking here... Maybe this will clarify: The output `9c74193 HEAD@{25}` would mean "`HEAD` has moved 25 times since it was at the commit whose abbreviated ID is 9c74193". In my examples I had to use placeholders, of course, since I didn't know the ID of any real commits (except the one you mentioned in your `reset` command)